# Putting a Listener on the transition animation between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

In android, is it possible to put a listener on the animation you get between activities, so that code can be executed at the end of the animation?

Comment: Would it not be easier just to have your code in the onCreate() method in the second activity?

Comment: Most of the time, yes. However if you start an animation in the onCreate() method when the transition animation is still running, it usually looks really bad. I want a way of ensuring the two animations don't run concurrently.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
Transition transition = getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition();
transition.addTarget(android.R.transition.slide_top);
transition.addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
        Log.e("transition ","onTransitionStart");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
        Log.e("transition ","onTransitionEnd");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a post delay of 1 second in the onCreate(). The activity animation duration is the same length no matter what so doing (new Handler()).postDelayed(Runnable) should do the trick, just fine tune the delay.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I've been doing, and I think it probably is the best solution. The trouble is that if my activity is being started by an intent from another application, the duration of the animation could have been changed by the other application using overridePendingTransition(). It would be much more satisfactory if the animation end could be detected.

Comment: Yeah true. OverridePendingTransition() definitely does mess things up